# Create non-anonymous AMD Modules in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to create non-anonymous AMD Modules in Typescript. When I define a module like this:

```
export module Bootstrapper {
  export function run() {
    var i = 0;
  }
}
```

the generate code is:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
  (function (Bootstrapper) {
    function run() {
        var i = 0;
    }
    Bootstrapper.run = run;
  })(exports.Bootstrapper || (exports.Bootstrapper = {}));
})
```

How can I define a non-anomymous module like this:

```
define('bootstrapper', ["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
  (function (Bootstrapper) {
    function run() {
        var i = 0;
    }
    Bootstrapper.run = run;
  })(exports.Bootstrapper || (exports.Bootstrapper = {}));
})
```

Comment: you could always write the requirejs code by hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the file [emitter.ts](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1d80dfedbf80#src%2fcompiler%2femitter.ts) at line 1202 (make a search for `" var dependencyList = "`) there is no implementation for it.

You can open an issue on codeplex about it.

Answer (score 6):

This feature was recently added to the TypeScript master branch via [this pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/1158). Declaring an AMD module name is with the following reference comment:

`/// <amd-module name='MyModuleName'/>`

will produce the following JavaScript:

`define("MyModuleName", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

As of TS 0.9.x it is not possible to name an AMD module.  The TS compiler will only generate a define statement in the format

```
define( ['dep1', 'dep2', ..., 'depN'], function( __dep1__, __dep2__, ..., __depN__ ) {... } );
```

discussion on the TS forums : https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/451454